# Access a dictionary inside a script tag using beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import time #to add delay

url ='https://www.fundoodata.com/companies-detail/Banctec-Tps-India-Pvt- 
Ltd/48600.html' #from where i need data
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)
links= soup.find('script')
print(links)
```

this gives-->

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Organization",
        "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "3rd Floor, Sharda Arcade, Pune Satara Road, 
Bibvewadi",
        "postalCode": "411016 ",
        "streetAddress": " Pune/Maharashtra "
      },
      "name": "Banctec Tps India Pvt Ltd",
      "telephone": "(020) "
    }
    </script>
```

i need to print out the address dictionary which is inside a dictionary, i need to access the addressLocality, postal code, streetaddress.
tried differnt methods and failed.

Comment: What exactly have you tried, and what did fail?

Comment: It should be `soup.find('script').string`

Comment: i'm new to python, since it was a dict i tried making it a list then accessing through key values, i tried accessing directly but it didn't work

Answer (score 4):

String of JSON formatted data in Python, deserialize that with json.loads()

```
import json
links= soup.find('script')
print(links)
```

after this,

```
address = json.loads(links.text)['address']
print(address)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the json package:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import time #to add dealay
import json

url ='https://www.fundoodata.com/companies-detail/Banctec-Tps-India-Pvt-Ltd/48600.html' #from where i need data
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)
links= soup.find_all('script')
print(links)


for script in links:
    if '@context' in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.string
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)

print (jsonObj['address'])
```

**Output:**

```
print (jsonObj['address'])
{'@type': 'PostalAddress', 'addressLocality': '3rd Floor, Sharda Arcade, Pune Satara Road, Bibvewadi', 'postalCode': '411016 ', 'streetAddress': ' Pune/Maharashtra '}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `string` property to get the text of the element, then you can parse it as JSON.

```
links_dict = json.loads(links.string)
address = links_dict['address']
```

Comment: hey Barmar, thanks it worked. is the address variable a dictionary now?

Comment: Yes, `json.loads()` loads the entire object into the dictionary.

Comment: You can do `print(links_dict)` to see the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Often times script tags contain a lot of javascript fluff. You can use regex to isolate the dictionary:

```
scripts = s.findAll('script')
    for script in scripts:
        if '@context' in script.text:

            # Extra step to isolate the dictionary.
            jsonStr = re.search(r'\{.*\}', str(script)).group()
            # Create dictionary
            dct = json.loads(jsonStr)

print(dct['address'])
```